# Two counters for beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, numbering

I am doing a presentation using beamer and it is quite long.
It is dividend in sections and at the end of each section I will do a break. Consequently, Iwould like to have a double counter of the current slide. For example:
Suppose I am currently at the 3rd slide of section 2 (made of 20 slides) and section 1 is made of 50 slides, the first counter will be 3/20 while the second 53/70 (if there are only two sections).

This is my working environment:

```
\documentclass[t,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
 \mode<presentation>
 {
 \usetheme{AnnArbor}
 \setbeamercovered{transparent}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
   \usecolortheme{spruce}
 }

  \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=White}
\section{Sec1}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{frame}{Fra 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Fra 2}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Fra 3}
\end{frame}
\section{Sec2}
\subsection{Sub 1}
\begin{frame}{Fra 1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Fra 2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any help?

Comment: The second counter is displayed in the footline by default. Where do you want to put the first counter?

Comment: I would like it of the footline as well on the left hand side, where currently I have only my name

Answer (score 4):

No new counters are needed, just a bit of calculation. Beamer stores the page numbers where a section starts and ends in macros `\insertsectionstartpage` and `\insertsectionendpage`. Thus the number of pages in a section can be calculated by

```
\insertsectionendpage-\insertsectionstartpage+1
```

The page number within a section is

```
\insertframenumber-\insertsectionstartpage+1
```

where `\insertframenumber` stores the page number of the current frame.

Patch these using `\patchcmd` from package `etoolbox` to the Beamer command that inserts the footline `\beamer@@tmpl@footline`, and you'll have section page counter on the left and overall page counter on the right in the footline.

## Code

```
\documentclass[t,10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{AnnArbor}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \useinnertheme{rounded}
  \usecolortheme{spruce}
}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=White}

\makeatletter
% change author box alignment 
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {center}% <search>
  {left}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>

% add page to author box
\patchcmd{\beamer@@tmpl@footline}% <cmd>
  {\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}}% <search>
  {\def\sectotpage{\number\numexpr\insertsectionendpage-\insertsectionstartpage+1}%
   \def\pageinsec{\number\numexpr\insertframenumber-\insertsectionstartpage+1}%
   \rlap{\hspace*{2ex}\pageinsec{} / \sectotpage} \hfill
  \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\beamer@ifempty\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}}% <replace>
  {}% <success>
  {}% <failure>
\makeatother

\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\nf{\frame{Frame in Section~\thesection.}}

\section{Sec 1}
\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf

\section{Sec 2}
\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf

\section{Sec 3}
\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf\nf

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: it does not seem to work for my case. The only think I have is that the position of the author is changed from centred to left. Any suggestions?

Comment: @tom: From what you're describing, it might be the case that this part of the code `\rlap{\hspace*{2ex}\pageinsec{} / \sectotpage} \hfill` is missing somehow. Could you check to see if it has been comment out accidentally in the process of copying & pasting?